# Default Screen Capture feature iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Could anyone please tell me  whether the iPad(device and not simulator) is taking any screenshot when we press home button for animation purpose just like in iPad simulator(which is storing in image-caches folder).

Also is this still happening for the latest simulators since there is no home button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which iPad, which OS level and build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How not to allow the iOS from taking a screen capture of your app before going into background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520076/how-not-to-allow-the-ios-from-taking-a-screen-capture-of-your-app-before-going-i)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that the list of applications obtained by sliding four or five fingers up on the screen includes a recent screenshot of each app, even though it might have been killed for memory purposes -- so yes, it must be doing as you describe.

Comment: so in device where it is saving.Also in the latest simulator still is taking screenshot

Comment: Yes; I did this before posting on a device, not in the simulator. I know that the screenshot is cached, not generated on demand, because it's there for apps that haven't been run for long enough that going back to them starts them over in a clean state.

Comment: ok.Thanks.in simulator we can access from the image-cache.Like that is there any location for the device.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question… are you asking about how to access the screenshots on the device so your own app might be able to do something with them? I don't think this is possible (and I can see some clear security violations if it were possible).

Comment: i just want to remove that feature for my app due to security issues.Also what about the latest simulator.

Comment: I can't tell you about the simulator. If you want to control the security aspect for your app, you _might_ be able to do that by reacting to whatever notification tells you you're being paused and change your primary UI to some static image. I don't know if that will work or not so you'll need to verify it. I'm sure your best results will be from responding to the earliest notification that suggests you're going to lose focus soon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40768/discussion-between-suji-and-mah)