# iOS 7+'s "Goodbye Snapshot"

Tags: ios, launching-application

This is an unusual one, but it's something I find a bit "quirky."

Since iOS 7, when an app is backgrounded (Home button pressed, and it resigns active), the OS takes a sceengrab of the app.

When the app is brought back to the fore, that screengrab is shown as the app re-launches. It's only a half second or so.

However, for the app I'm working on, that screenshot is misleading. The device has been disconnected, so the data displayed is completely wrong.

1) I'd like to be able to replace the screengrab with the LaunchImage (which I specify) as it is shown; even if the app is being "reawakened."

Is this something that I can do?

2) Maybe there's a way for me to replace the stored screengrab?

3) If I can get sufficient notice (There does not seem to be a message before the screengrab is taken), then I can replace the screen with the LaunchImage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How not to allow the iOS from taking a screen capture of your app before going into background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520076/how-not-to-allow-the-ios-from-taking-a-screen-capture-of-your-app-before-going-i)

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7520307/909655 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/18961652/909655

Comment: @Mats I think that nailed it! If you make this an answer, I'll greencheck you! Thanks!

Comment: Yeaaahhh...None of this stuff is working. I'll dig into it more. I have a feeling that it's because a lot of the program execution happens in callbacks from BSD Sockets. Even though I push them to execute in the main thread, the system still seems a bit wonky. For example, if I breakpoint in Swift, Xcode crashes. I need to break in the underlying ObjC framework to catch states. Then, if I step into Swift -BOOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to know when an app is going to resign active or be backgrounded. The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol defines the method `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` which is called before an application is moved from active to inactive.

Knowing the timing of that method's invocation, you can do whatever you want before the app goes inactive. So, you could toss a view on top of the screen that contains whatever you want. This would then become the multitasking image, and the launch image.

Reference the following blog post for a more in depth analysis: http://blog.adambell.ca/post/73339778302/dynamic-ios-multitasking

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't work. However, it may be because the drawing routines haven't triggered. Maybe I need to figure out how to immediately force the drawing.

Comment: BTW: Thanks for the link. It may give me what I need. I need to spend some quality time with it.

Comment: @MAGSHARE what have you tried? I just created a single view project and did exactly what I described, and it worked. [Here](https://gist.github.com/amonshiz/fff04597d0090c28b80c) is a gist of the app delegate, which is the only thing I had to modify.

Comment: Hm...What I did was overlay the screen with a hidden UIImageView (the LaunchImage). I have this as an overlay during launch, and hide it when the first image is displayed from the device. I am unhiding it (which may be an issue -maybe that is too low a priority?). In any case, I was directed to a duplicate question, and that may have the answer for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find anything that was an explicit call to make, but you might be able to trick the system. The protocol method `[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:]` will take a new snapshot of your user interface when you call the `completionHandler`. If you register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, this is called shortly before the transition starts. You could try launching an `NSURLSession` that you intend to complete immediately when handling the notification, then calling the `completionHandler`.

It's very likely that the timing won't work out since they'll be on different threads, but it's worth a shot.