# How do I implement a privacy screen when app is not active?

Tags: ios, swift, security

Many banking apps implement a static image when the user is switching apps or multitasking. Then when the app is opened again, the user is prompted to login/use TouchID. I figured I should launch a view controller (`animated: false`) from `applicationWillResignActive` in `AppDelegate`, but the underlying view is still visible when multitasking.

How should this privacy view be implemented?

Comment: Did it also not work for `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: It works after switching apps - thanks

Comment: Below might help you to hide screen when switching apps :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959411/controlling-the-screenshot-in-the-ios-7-multitasking-switcher

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792850/display-a-view-or-splash-screen-before-applicationdidenterbackground-to-avoid-a

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520076/how-not-to-allow-the-ios-from-taking-a-screen-capture-of-your-app-before-going-i

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to present view from `applicationDidEnterBackground`