# Why does my iOS App launch screen disappears while loading and then reappears?

Tags: ios, loading, launch-screen

I have a launch screen equal to a RootViewController I created for loading purposes.
What happens is that if I kill the app, and then reopen it, it goes like this:

1. Launch Screen appears.
2. Launch Screen disappears and I can see my main view for a split second.
3. Launch Screen reappears and finishes loading.

This is pretty weird since I don't seem to have any control over this.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520307/4311935

Comment: @canister_exister perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quirk of iOS card handling - nothing you can do to avoid that, except for making your rootViewController resemble the launch screen just after launch. Similar to the Twitter app...

Comment: I already did that, both LaunchScreen and RootViewController nibs are equal :(